# Test runner tab disappeared in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, automated-tests, intellij-13, test-runner

When I try to run the tests by right-click and selecting "Run.."

It used to work until a few days ago. I use IntelliJ 2021, I tried an older version but I have the same issue, I tried uninstalling most of my plugins, nothing. I also tried searching through similar issues but nothing was of use.

[This is how the Run Tab looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBtlF.png)

In the Run tab, a list of running tests should be seen, but it is not. My project is a Maven project with Java and Gauge. Do you have any idea what the problem could be? My guess is I either pressed something by mistake or something else is doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just found the issue, please make sure to have

[this checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAcHM.png)

checked if you use Gauge.